# Can we use Xamarin.iOS 's CoreLocation API for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, core-location

sorry if the question is confusing. So I'm switching from Swift to Xamarin (which I'm pretty new to) in order to make cross-platform applications. So my app uses the **CoreLocation** framework to work with the iBeacons and locating stuff. I managed to make a similar version with Xamarin.iOS and that's all. I don't really get the idea that "*Xamarin gives you the opportunity to share as much code as possible over different platforms*" in this situation. Things just go buggy and messed up everytime I create the cross-platform (Xamarin.Forms).

My **Xamarin.iOS** code is here in case it helps:

```
...
using CoreLocation;
...
// Start scanning for beacons
            void StartScanningForBeacons()
            {
                #region
                //var Uuid = new NSUuid();
                //var BeaconRegion = new CLBeaconRegion(Uuid,BeaconId);    
                LocationManager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();

                #endregion

                // Start ranging beacons
                LocationManager.StartRangingBeacons(BeaconRegion);


                // DidRangeBeacons
                LocationManager.DidRangeBeacons += (object sender, CLRegionBeaconsRangedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    // Push beacons' information onto screen
                    //Create Alert
                    var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Title", "We found " + e.Beacons.Length + " beacon(s)\nmajor: " + e.Beacons[0].Major, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                    //Add Action
                    okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

                    // Present Alert
                    PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
                    // DisplayBeaconsInformation(e.Beacons);
                };                
            }
...
```

So, my question is, can we implement a specific iOS framework into Xamarin.Forms, then replicate the whole code from my Xamarin.iOS and expect it to run on both Android and iOS platform?

Comment: No.  iOS APIs aren't available on an Android device.

Comment: So in this case I cannot make the app for both platforms from a same code base? Anyway thanks for replying.

Comment: Xamarin provides cross-platform abstractions that allow you to write code that will build for both platforms but utilize the appropriate platform specific libraries at runtime.